# If statement on Django template based on model data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have an if statement on my django template on what to display. but It wont change, it stays at `*No warning*`, whats wrong in my code? Thanks!

**condition**: if my app detects 15 entries of `extreme` it will display `Warning` else if it detects more than 15 entries of `extreme` it will display `Critical`.

models.py

```
class Data(models.Model):
    level = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, default='')
    amount = models.FloatField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def update_level(self):
        if 0.1 <= self.amount < 2.5:
            return 'Low'
        elif 2.5 <= self.amount < 7.5:
            return 'Medium'
        elif 7.5 < self.amount < 15:
            return 'High'
        elif 15 <= self.amount < 30:
            return 'Very High'
        elif 30 <= self.amount < 200:
            return 'Extreme'
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    num = Data.objects.all()
    context = {'num': num}
    return render(request, 'analytics.html', context)
```

html

```
<h3>{{ num.level }}</h3>
{% if num.level < 15 %}
<h3 style="color:red;">Critical</h3>
{% elif num.level == 15 %}
<h3 style="color:yellow;">Warning</h3>
{% else %}
<h3>No Warning</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong within the template itself.

The issue is `num = Data.objects.all()` returns a querySet of all `Data` entries, which doesn't have a `level` field itself.

To get the number of entries matching a certain critera, you can use `filter` and `count`:

```py
num_extreme = Data.objects.filter(level='Extreme').count() # Returns the number of DB entries with 'Extreme' level
```

Then in your template, you can use conditions:

```
{% if num_extreme > 15 %}
<h3 style="color:red;">Critical</h3>
{% end %}
```

Comment: For example, in 30 entries of levels in the database. and there are 15 or more entries of 'Extreme' then it must display 'Critical'. is it possible to detect `Extreme` as specified level in my code? or in `num = Data.objects.first()` ?

Comment: It's very unclear to me why you want to achieve. Are your trying to display different message according to the number of entries matching a certain critera?

Comment: Yes. `trying to display different message according to the number of entries matching a certain critera`. It's like a `status` of my data in model.